# R Shiny: Right Align and Left Align in the Same Dropdown Menu

Tags: r, shiny, dropdown

I am making an R Shiny app and would like to left align and right align in the same dropdown menu.

So in the example app:

```
library(shiny)


# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Dropdown Problems"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions 
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs 
    sidebarPanel(

    # Define Dropdown Menu
    selectizeInput("selection_dropdown", "Select Selection of Interest:",
        choices=NULL,
        options=list(
          maxItems=1,
          placeholder='Select Selection',
          create=TRUE)
        )
    ),
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

    # Output: 
    plotOutput(outputId = "sample_plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(session,input, output) {

# Define New Data Frame 
new_data_frame <- data.frame(column1=c("aaaaaaaa","bb","cccc"),column2=c(1,2,3),column3=c("plot_a","plot_b","plot_c"))

# Create Dropdown Menu 
observe({
dropdown_choices <- paste(new_data_frame$column1," (",new_data_frame$column2,")",sep="")
updateSelectizeInput(
            session,
            "selection_dropdown",
            choices=dropdown_choices,
            server=TRUE,
            )
            })
# Create Output Plot (This doesn't really matter)
output$sample_plot <- renderPlot({
    plot_selection <- gsub(" .*","",input$selection_dropdown)
    plot_selection <- new_data_frame$column3[new_data_frame$column1==plot_selection]
    plot(
    x=NA,
    y=NA,
    xlim=c(0,100),
    ylim=c(0,100)
    )
    text(x=50,y=50,plot_selection)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In the dropdown menu I would like the letters to be left aligned within the dropdown and the numbers and brackets to be right aligned.

I can separate them by a tab but the numbers won't be in line with each other unfortunately.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a new column that combines column 1 and 2, then a little bit of Javascript is used to create HTML for each option.

It left aligns the value from column 1 and right aligns the value from column 2.

It can probably be done without creating the new column by passing the 2 columns to the Javascript function.

```
library(shiny)


# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Dropdown Problems"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions 
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs 
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # Define Dropdown Menu
      selectizeInput("selection_dropdown", "Select Selection of Interest:",
                     choices=NULL,
                     options=list(
                       maxItems=1,
                       placeholder='Select Selection',
                       create=TRUE)
      )
    ),
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      # Output: 
      plotOutput(outputId = "sample_plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(session,input, output) {
  
  # Define New Data Frame 
  new_data_frame <- data.frame(column1=c("aaaaaaaa","bb","cccc"),column2=c(1,2,3),column3=c("plot_a","plot_b","plot_c"))
  new_data_frame$column4 <-paste0(new_data_frame$column1, " (", new_data_frame$column2, ")")
  # Create Dropdown Menu 
  observe({
    dropdown_choices <- new_data_frame$column4
    updateSelectizeInput(
      session,
      "selection_dropdown",
      choices=dropdown_choices,
      options = list(render = I(
        '{
    option: function(item, escape) {
      const x = item.value.split(" ");
      return `<p style=\"text-align:left;\">
    ${x[0]}
    <span style=\"float:right;\">
        ${x[1]}
    </span>
</p>`
    }
  }')),
      server=TRUE,
    )
  })
  
  # Create Output Plot (This doesn't really matter)
  output$sample_plot <- renderPlot({
    plot_selection <- gsub(" .*","",input$selection_dropdown)
    plot_selection <- new_data_frame$column3[new_data_frame$column1==plot_selection]
    plot(
      x=NA,
      y=NA,
      xlim=c(0,100),
      ylim=c(0,100)
    )
    text(x=50,y=50,plot_selection)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You're a wizard. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

How about this
[image]

We can use the `counter` trick from CSS so these numbers are automatically assigned based on the order they are displayed in the dropdown. It means you don't need to manually add the index. When it is selected, on the server, it returns the value without the index.

```r
library(shiny)


# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$style(
        '
        :root {counter-reset: mycounter;}
        .selectize-dropdown-content .option::after {
            counter-increment: mycounter;
            content: "(" counter(mycounter) ")";
            float: right;
        }
        '
    ),
    # App title ----
    titlePanel("Dropdown Problems"),
    # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions 
    sidebarLayout(
        
        # Sidebar panel for inputs 
        sidebarPanel(
            
            # Define Dropdown Menu
            selectizeInput("selection_dropdown", "Select Selection of Interest:",
                           choices=NULL,
                           options=list(
                               maxItems=1,
                               placeholder='Select Selection',
                               create=TRUE)
            )
        ),
        # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
        mainPanel(
            
            # Output: 
            plotOutput(outputId = "sample_plot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(session,input, output) {
    
    # Define New Data Frame 
    new_data_frame <- c("aaaaaaaa","bb","cccc")
    
    # Create Dropdown Menu 
    observe({
        updateSelectizeInput(
            session,
            "selection_dropdown",
            choices=new_data_frame,
            server=TRUE,
        )
    })
    # Create Output Plot (This doesn't really matter)
    output$sample_plot <- renderPlot({
        plot_selection <- gsub(" .*","",input$selection_dropdown)
        plot(
            x=NA,
            y=NA,
            xlim=c(0,100),
            ylim=c(0,100)
        )
        text(x=50,y=50,plot_selection)
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

### Updates:

If your indices are not ordered numbers, we can still do it.
I just assume your data is still sending options from the server, even though your demo data seems that it can be done purely from the UI. Imagine your indices are some random numbers. We can send these numbers as CSS style to UI and format the dropdown.

[image]

```r
library(shiny)
library(glue)
library(magrittr)
# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
    # App title ----
    titlePanel("Dropdown Problems"),
    # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions 
    sidebarLayout(
        
        # Sidebar panel for inputs 
        sidebarPanel(
            
            # Define Dropdown Menu
            uiOutput("style"),
            selectizeInput("selection_dropdown", "Select Selection of Interest:",
                           choices=NULL,
                           options=list(
                               maxItems=1,
                               placeholder='Select Selection',
                               create=TRUE)
            )
        ),
        # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
        mainPanel(
            
            # Output: 
            plotOutput(outputId = "sample_plot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(session,input, output) {
    
    # Define New Data Frame 
    new_data_frame <- c("aaaaaaaa","bb","cccc")
    indices <- sample(999, 3)
    output$style <- renderUI(
        tags$style(glue(.open = '@{', .close = "}@",
            '
            .selectize-dropdown-content .option:nth-child(@{seq_along(indices)}@)::after {
                content: "(@{indices}@)";
                float: right;
            }
            '
        ) %>% glue_collapse("\n"))
    )
    # Create Dropdown Menu 
    observe({
        updateSelectizeInput(
            session,
            "selection_dropdown",
            choices=new_data_frame,
            server=TRUE,
        )
    })
    # Create Output Plot (This doesn't really matter)
    output$sample_plot <- renderPlot({
        plot_selection <- gsub(" .*","",input$selection_dropdown)
        plot(
            x=NA,
            y=NA,
            xlim=c(0,100),
            ylim=c(0,100)
        )
        text(x=50,y=50,plot_selection)
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. It certainly solves the problem as presented here. Unfortunately in the real data column2 isn't necessarily 1,2,3 etc. in order, it can be any numerical value.

Comment: Brilliant thanks, I've accepted the other answer as it is more intuitive to me but this also seems perfect. Thanks so much for your help and time.